# .loc function for a specific label returning an empty data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-loc

For context, I'm trying to filter out rows in my dataframe that only belong to the year 2021.

This is my script code:

`test = all_SS_batting_columns.loc[all_SS_batting_columns['Year'] == '2021']`

but it only returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [index, Year, Age, Tm, Lg, G, PA, AB, R, H, 2B, 3B, HR, RBI, SB, CS, BB, SO, BA, OBP, SLG]
Index: []
```

Just in case, here's what my dataframe looks like:

```
   index           Year   Age   Tm   Lg    G  ...  CS  BB   SO     BA    OBP    SLG
0      0           2016  23.0  CHW   AL   99  ...   2  13  117  0.283  0.306  0.432
1      1           2017  24.0  CHW   AL  146  ...   1  13  162  0.257  0.276  0.402
2      2           2018  25.0  CHW   AL  153  ...   8  30  149  0.240  0.281  0.406
3      3           2019  26.0  CHW   AL  123  ...   5  15  109  0.335  0.357  0.508
4      4           2020  27.0  CHW   AL   49  ...   2  10   50  0.322  0.357  0.529
5      5           2021  28.0  CHW   AL   88  ...   7  18   87  0.299  0.332  0.437
6      6          6 Yrs   NaN  NaN  NaN  658  ...  25  99  674  0.283  0.312  0.442
7      7  162 Game Avg.   NaN  NaN  NaN  162  ...   6  24  166  0.283  0.312  0.442
8      0           2019  21.0  TOR   AL   46  ...   4  14   50  0.311  0.358  0.571
9      1           2020  22.0  TOR   AL   29  ...   1   5   27  0.301  0.328  0.512
[10 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: Are you sure the data type of Year is string (object)? Because you are doing string comparison. Try `all_SS_batting_columns.loc[all_SS_batting_columns['Year'].astype(str) == '2021']`

Comment: Yeah it was an object. The data in the dataframe were either object, int, float...no strings. Thank you for the code, it solved the issue and I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate df name to see all columns:

```
 test = all_SS_batting_columns[all_SS_batting_columns.loc[all_SS_batting_columns['Year'] == '2021']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `where` instead of `loc`.

```
test = all_SS_batting_columns.where[all_SS_batting_columns['Year'] == '2021']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter Dataframe for Year 2021 , use -
No need to use loc

```
test = all_SS_batting_columns[all_SS_batting_columns['Year'] == '2021']
test
```